# Can you become a werewolf vampire hybrid the second time you are trying to be werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In skyrim I am trying to become a vampire/werewolf hybrid. originally you supposed to do the Dawnguard questline completely so that way you can get turned into a vampire lord again afterwards. You're supposed to completed the companion quest line to a point where you can become a werewolf, then you're supposed to drink the blood to become a werewolf and turn into a vampire lord at the same time to glitch out the game. It allows you to keep both the werewolf form and the vampire lord form without any of the vampire Lords weaknesses and can keep the vampire Lords eyes and face. My Problem is that I've already done the complete companions quest line and became a werewolf and I cure myself of being a werewolf by becoming a vampire lord, but now I want to become a hybrid. So my question is would I be able to become A hybrid but by using the second time u can become a werewolf?

Comment: No it is a completely different question I'm asking if you can still become a hybrid even if you've already done the companion quest line became a werewolf

Comment: There is no code in the original game nor in its expansions to support becoming a werewolf/vampire hybrid, werewolf and vampire are mutually exclusive.  If you're playing with some mod that allows you to become a hybrid anyway it'll probably be specified in the readme what you need to do.  That said, as this question stands  I'm voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: That's just a special case of the previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla Skyrim, you can't be both. If you have PC, you can use this mod to be both. http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25095/?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: You can not. Except through mods or maybe through cheats.
The game in its vanilla status has no legal possibility to gain both advantages.

Comment: Look you may not know how but i have done it before with a mod or cheat i use a console so i can't cheat

Comment: Please read carefully: I said "Except through mods or cheats" so if you have done it through a mod, as you say, you should ask the developer how that works. On the maingame it is not possible, there you have to choose.

Comment: Sorry i meant to say without a mod or cheat and it worked but that time I did it the way i described it above this time it's different because I'm trying to do with the second time ucan become a werewolf

Comment: To Glitch a game is cheating, just not by console and to use bugs can cause your game to completely get broken and for that I can not help you, sorry. And thus my answer is completely legit: Legally impossible. Sorry.